# how to create query to generate safe single quote?

Tags: sql-server

Sorry if my question not clear,

this issue is simple, i want to make a query that result an insert quert. for example in mssql :

```
select concat('insert into sometable (name) values (''', fullname , ''');') from usertable;
```

in this case will give result :

```
insert into some table (name) values ('Yoza');
```

but i got problem with user with name have single quote like `'arafah'` or `jum'at`

the result i got now :

```
insert into some table (name) values (''arafah'); 
insert into some table (name) values ('jum'at');
```

it will make and error, i wish it be :

```
insert into some table (name) values ('''arafah'); 
insert into some table (name) values ('jum''at');
```

so can be safe in other sql execution.

please help me how to solve it? because i dont know the keyword to google it

Answer (score 1):

As @JoeObbish pointed out in a comment, simply parameterize the query.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t (SomeCol varchar(100));

DECLARE @param varchar(100);
SET @param = 'Max''s Test';

INSERT INTO dbo.t (SomeCol) VALUES (@param);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.t;
```

Results:

```
╔════════════╗
║  SomeCol   ║
╠════════════╣
║ Max's Test ║
╚════════════╝
```

Client software typically offers variety of ways to accomplish the same thing, however almost all of the time you simply need to look up "parameterization" in the documentation.

If you need to make the contents of the `SomeCol` value into a parameter for use in a generated T-SQL script, you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
SET @cmd = N'';
SELECT @cmd = @cmd + CASE WHEN @cmd = N'' THEN N'' ELSE CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) END 
    + N'SET @p = ' + QUOTENAME(t.SomeCol, N'''') + N';
INSERT INTO dbo.c (MyVal) VALUES (@p);'
FROM dbo.t;
SET @cmd = N'DECLARE @p varchar(100);
' + @cmd;
PRINT @cmd;
```

The above `PRINT` command output:

```
DECLARE @p varchar(100);
    SET @p = 'Max''s Test';
    INSERT INTO dbo.c (MyVal) VALUES (@p);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to insert some rows into one table based on values in another, then look at the "insert ... select" variant of the Insert statement.

```
insert into table2( a, b, c )
select x, y, z 
from table1 ;
```